# Взять айдишники из двух таблиц и сложить в другую таблицу

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

[image: Отсюда нужно взять id(A_I)]

[image: и отсюда нужно взять id(A_I]

[image: Внедрить сюда]

Пробовал через `INSERT INTO ...` данные получается засунуть но идет как на 3 фотографии (Сперва заполняется 1 столбик потом другой)

Код того как я делал

```
$stmt= $pdo->prepare("
    INSERT INTO
        `cuisines` (
            `name`
        ) VALUES (
            :name
        )        
");

foreach ($cuisines as $cuisine) {
    $stmt->execute([
        ':name'=> $cuisine
    ]);

    $last_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO restaurants_cuisines (id_cuisine) VALUES ($last_id)";
    $pdo->exec($sql);
}

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    Insert INTO 
        `restaurants` (
            `name`,
            `link`,
            `price_min`,
            `price_max`,
            `worktime`,
            `address`
        ) VALUES (
            :name,
            :link,
            :price_min,
            :price_max,
            :worktime,
            :address
        )
");

foreach ($globalRests as $rest){
    $stmt->execute([
        ':name' => $rest['name'],
        ':link' => $rest['link'],
        ':price_min' => $rest['price']['price_min'],
        ':price_max' => $rest['price']['price_max'],
        ':worktime' => $rest['worktime'],
        ':address' => $rest['address']
    ]);
    $last_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO restaurants_cuisines (id_restaurant) VALUES ($last_id)";
    $pdo->exec($sql);
}
```

Comment: Совершенно не понятно чего вы пытаетесь добиться. но что бы данные садились в несколько столбцов в одну запись, то они должны быть записаны одной операцией insert

Comment: да мне именно это нужно. но как это реализовать не могу понять @Mike. так как у меня 2 `foreach` в коде

Comment: 2 вас 2 foreach потому что 2 массива данных. вам надо решить по какому принципу объединить информацию из этих 2х массивов. например если в них одинаково количество записей и их данные должны идти паралельно, то переделать foreach на обычный for и читать по номеру элемента из обоих массивов. Ну или если отношения более сложные продумать логику для какого элемента первого массива какие данные брать из второго